# How to remove single component from object in gridstack Vue3

Tags: chart.js, vuejs3, gridstack

I am trying to remove a single component from an object in gridstack.js using index and keys. Components are created by v-for directive.

I already have the index and key but components.splice(index,1) and grid.removeWidget(key, false); functions don't achieve this as shown in the [documentation](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js). What I am i doing wrong.

Thanks

```
<template>
    <div class="right">
        <button class="ds" @click="addNewWidget()">Add Widget</button>
         //works okay
        <button class="ds" @click="deleteWidget()">Clear</button>
    </div>

    <section class="grid-stack">
        <div v-for="(component, key, index) in components" :key="'component' + index" :gs-id="key"
            class="grid-stack-item" :gs-x="component.gridPos.x" :gs-y="component.gridPos.y" :gs-h="component.gridPos.h"
            :gs-w="component.gridPos.w" gs-auto-position="true">
            <div class="grid-stack-item-content">
                <component :is="component.name" v-bind="component.props" />
              //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'splice')
                <button @click="remove(index, key, component)">remove</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
  
<script>
import { ref, onMounted, reactive, nextTick } from 'vue';
import "gridstack/dist/h5/gridstack-dd-native";
import 'gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css';
import { GridStack } from 'gridstack';
import BarChart from './BarChart.vue';
import PieChart from './PieChart.vue';
import LineChart from './LineChart.vue';
import Widget from './HalfDoughnut.vue';

export default {
    name: "Dashboard",
    setup() {
        let info = ref("");
        let grid = null;

        let components = reactive({
            yourRandomComponent1: {
                name: "BarChart", props: {}, gridPos: { x: 0, y: 1, w: 6, h: 7 }
            },
            yourRandomComponent2: {
                name: "PieChart", props: {}, gridPos: { x: 0, y: 1, w: 6, h: 7 }
            },
        });

        onMounted(() => {
            grid = GridStack.init({
                float: true,
                cellHeight: "70px",
                minRow: 1,
            });

            grid.on("dragstop", (event, element) => {
                console.log("move event!", event, element);
                const node = element.gridstackNode;
                info.value = `you just dragged node #${node.id} to ${node.x},${node.y} – good job!`;
            });
        });

        // this will of course only work once because of the object-key
        function addNewWidget() {
            components.yourRandomComponent3 = {
                name: "Widget", props: {}, gridPos: { x: 0, y: 1, w: 6, h: 7 }
            };

            // we have to wait for vue to update v-for, 
            // until then the querySelector wont find the element
            nextTick(() => {
                console.log(grid);
                let compEl = document.querySelector('[gs-id="yourRandomComponent3"]');
                console.log(compEl);
                grid.makeWidget(compEl);
            });
            console.warn("i will only work once, fix my inputs to reuse me");
        }
        function remove(index, key) {
            console.log(key)
            //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'splice')
            components.splice(index, 1);
            grid.removeWidget(key, false);

        }
        function deleteWidget(){
            grid.removeAll(true);
        }

        return {
            info,
            components,
            addNewWidget,
            deleteWidget,
            remove
        };
    },
    components: {
        // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-unused-components
        BarChart, PieChart, LineChart, Widget
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are declaring `components` as a `reactive` which means you don't need to use `.value` use `delete componennts[key]` but a regular object

also use `const` to declare `ref`, `reactive`... to avoid errors

Comment: thanks @Tachibana Shin. I try components.splice(index, 1) but getting Uncaught TypeError: components.splice is not a function.

Comment: @user10415598 I didn't read your code carefully I will correct my answer now

Comment: please check answer.  `delete.components[key]` will not work. Also if I declare const on components I will not be able to change the constant which I want to.thnks

Comment: which i bet it will work at least with vue 3 also if you want to change the value of components you can use ref instead of assigning variables directly. Direct variable assignments will not be accepted in vue

if you want me to go deeper please create a minimally reproducible example

Comment: you know what i mean `delete components[key]` not `delete.components[key]` if you do what i say the worst case will just be gridstack library giving error and sure 1 item in `grid-stack` will be removed

Comment: of course yes but it would be better if we talk to each other instead of using stackoverflow your code has a lot of problems. do you have discord?

Comment: I am a `tachib_shin#7354`.  send message for me

Comment: okay, I sent request.